# Multiple SPARK installs and SCALA dependencies

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking at putting SPARK 2.x on my VM.

However, do I need to install Scala specifically again?

I have SPARK 1.6 that calls Scala 2.10, but I cannot find where that Scala bin / library etc. is and if I can re-use it therefore? A find shows many scala files and references under many locations, e.g. Hadoop places:

```
 /home/cloudera/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler
```

The tutorials all point to installing if scala -version shows nothing.

Looking for guidance. NB: This is not about SBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala dependencies are compile-time dependencies for Spark.

You won't need to install Scala to be able to run Spark shell or application with Spark-submit.

Comment: @thebluephantom it already knows it (as it was compiled with specific version and holds this version inside of pom file)

Comment: then it means a post I am reading https://idroot.net/linux/install-apache-spark-centos-7/ is not correct or no longer valid(?) @gemelen

Comment: I don't know why author added Scala to installation steps. Neither spark-shell nor spark-submit requires Scala jars.
Only suggestion is that tutorial expects you delelop your apps on the same host.

Comment: Then I understand it as I always thought I did - and was fooled. Thanks